# How can I extend a module, override a method, and still call the overridden method?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to use URI in this way:

```
require 'open-uri'
uri = URI.parse('http://subdomain.domain.com/section/page.html')
puts uri.first_level_domain # => 'domain.com'
```

How can I do that?

I'm trying:

```
module URI
    def parse
        ret = super
        domain = ret.host.split('.').last(2).join('.')
        ret.send(:define_method, :first_level_domain, lambda { domain })        
        ret
    end
end
```

but I get `undefined method 'first_level_domain' for #<URI::HTTP:0x9bc7ab0> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Here you don't need it, but may take a look at `alias_method_chain` anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why something so complicated ? You could something like this

```
module URI
  def first_level_domain
    host.split('.').last(2).join('.')
  end
end

uri = URI.parse('http://subdomain.domain.com/section/page.html')
uri.first_level_domain
# => "domain.com"
```